# listview with custom adapter is not showing thumbnail…instead its showing diffrent picture2

Tags: android, listview, adapter

```
              CustomVideoAdapter VideolistAdapter = new CustomVideoAdapter(this, songs);
                audiolistview.setAdapter(VideolistAdapter);
                audiolistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                        music_column_index = musicCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                        cursorPoristion = i;
                        musicCursor.moveToPosition(i);
                        String filename = musicCursor.getString(music_column_index);
                        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
                        mediaController.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
                        mediaController.setEnabled(true);
                        videoView.setVideoPath(filename);
                        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
                        videoView.start();
                        videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
                    }
                });
```

//customAdapter for list

```
public class CustomVideoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<AudioModel> rowItems;


 public CustomVideoAdapter(Context context, List<AudioModel> items) {
    this.context = context;
    this.rowItems = items;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtDesc;
}



      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    AudioModel rowItem = (AudioModel) getItem(position);
    String path=rowItem.getaPath();
    Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);

    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getaName());
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(thumb);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return rowItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return rowItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
}
```

}

1.when running this application code I am not getting the thumbnail of the video files list and video is not showing but sound is playing.

2.I have set two different custom adapter to show video list and audio list...the problem I am getting here is video list is not showing as expected from the video list layout...

Comment: musicCursor.getString(music_column_index); is it returns a valid file

Comment: it returns file path

Comment: Show us your ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail() method

Comment: i have used that...plz read description before answering question